# Evitar inserción si no se cumple una expresión regular

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Estoy estudiando los disparadores(Triggers) en MySQL, y me resulta un problema al aplicar filtros al insertar un elemento a una tabla respectiva. Necesito que no acepte la inserción si detecta caracteres especiales.

Lo hice de esta manera:

```
create trigger verifydata
    before insert
    on person
    for each row
    begin
        if(not new.name RLIKE '[A-Za-z]') then
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Verify name';
        end if;
    end;@
delimiter ;
```

Pero no funciona.

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de hacer este trigger? ¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: normalmente los Triggers son usados para cosas no relacionadas con la tabla en la que estas haciendo algo.

Comment: La programación es mejor hacerla con el lenguaje que uses y ya después haz la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error esta en la forma en la que estas manejando tu expresion regular, me parece que la manera correcta debe ser esta

```
REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```